# Display first two positions in nested tree

Tags: xml, xslt, position, ancestor

I'm new to XSL and learning as I go. I'm currently editing a third party stylesheet for XML created locally, part of which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl">

<c01>
    <did>
        <unittitle>Annual Reports</unittitle>
        <physdesc>19 folders</physdesc>                                   
    </did>
    <scopecontent>
        <p>Annual reports...</p>
    </scopecontent>
    <c02>
        <did>
            <container type="box">1</container>
            <container type="folder">1</container>
            <unittitle>1839-40, 1846 (SPP); 1852 (BPA); 1854 (SPP)</unittitle>
        </did>
    </c02>
    <c02>
         <did>
            <container type="folder">2</container>
            <unittitle>1869, 1872 (BPA); 1873 (IAS)</unittitle>
         </did>
    </c02>

<c01>
     <did>
         <unittitle>Bulletins</unittitle>
         <physdesc>2 folders</physdesc>
     </did>
     <scopecontent>
         <p>Bulletins...</p>
     </scopecontent>
     <c02>
         <did>
             <container type="box">1</container>
             <container type="folder">21</container>
             <unittitle>Bulletins 1945-46</unittitle>
         </did>
     </c02>
     <c02>
         <did>
         <container type="box">2</container>
         <container type="folder">1</container>
         <unittitle>Bulletins 1946-51</unittitle>
         </did>
     </c02>
</c01>
```

With some XSL that creates a table for the many `<c01>`s, `<c02>`s, etc, that looks partially like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="ISO-8859-1" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"/>

<xsl:template match="c02/did">
<tr>    
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="ancestor::c01/descendant::c02/did/container">
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <th><xsl:value-of select="container[1]/@type"/></th>
                <th><xsl:value-of select="container[2]/@type"/></th>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</tr>
</xsl:template>
```

A table is created prior to this template in the XSL which creates multiple columns, the first two of which are to have `<th>`s that pull the `<container type>` (usually "Box" and "Folder"). Each `<container type>` should only appear once per `<c01>`, which it should pull from the first `<c02>`. Sometimes there are `<c02>`s with only one `<container type>`, sometimes `<c01>`s have multiple `<c02>`s with both `<container type="box">` & `<container type="folder">`.

I've tried many variations of `position()=1` and using `<xsl:choose>`/`<xsl:when>`, pretty much everything I can think of. It either always displays a `<th>` for every instance of `<container type="box">` & `<container type="folder">` or displays `<th>`s every time there are two `<container type>`s.

Any ideas?

**Update with actual (undesired) output**
I was asked to provide some desired/actual XML output. This is my best attempt at conveying the actual HTML output (since I can't copy/paste it), disregarding everything from `<c01>` through `</scopecontent>` (because I have that part figured out):

```
<tr>
<th>Box</th>
<th>Folder</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1839-40, 1846 (SPP); 1852 (BPA); 1854 (SPP)</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Folder</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td>2</td>
<td>1869, 1872 (BPA); 1873 (IAS)</td>
</tr>

...

<tr>
<th>Box</th>
<th>Folder</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>21</td>
<td>Bulletins 1945-46</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Box</th>
<th>Folder</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>Bulletins 1946-51</td>
</tr>
```

**Desired output**

```
<tr>
<th>Box</th>
<th>Folder</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1839-40, 1846 (SPP); 1852 (BPA); 1854 (SPP)</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td>2</td>
<td>1869, 1872 (BPA); 1873 (IAS)</td>
</tr>

...

<tr>
<th>Box</th>
<th>Folder</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>21</td>
<td>Bulletins 1945-46</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>Bulletins 1946-51</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The prose is a good attempt to explain what's needed, but not completely clear. Can you post desired XML output that demonstrates what you want? It would be even more helpful to post actual XML output that demonstrates what's going wrong with your existing code.

Comment: @LarsH Updated with both actual & desired output. Hope the helps!

Comment: Yes, very helpful! Please see my posted solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well I thought at first this was a grouping problem calling for [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

But then I looked closer and changed my mind. Here's how I would do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="ISO-8859-1"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" />

  <xsl:template match="c01">
    <xsl:variable name="c01ID" select="generate-id()" />
    <tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="c02[1]//container">
        <th>
          <xsl:value-of select="@type" />
        </th>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="c02" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="c02/did">
    <tr>
      <xsl:variable name="contextDid" select="." />
      <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::c01/c02[1]//container/@type">
        <xsl:variable name="currentType" select="." />

        <td>
          <xsl:value-of
            select="$contextDid/container[@type = $currentType]/text()" />
        </td>
      </xsl:for-each>

      <xsl:for-each select="unittitle">
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </td>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run against the following sample input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?>

<root>
  <c01>
    <did>
      <unittitle>Annual Reports</unittitle>
      <physdesc>19 folders</physdesc>
    </did>
    <scopecontent>
      <p>Annual reports...</p>
    </scopecontent>
    <c02>
      <did>
        <container type="box">1</container>
        <container type="folder">1</container>
        <unittitle>1839-40, 1846 (SPP); 1852 (BPA); 1854 (SPP)</unittitle>
      </did>
    </c02>
    <c02>
      <did>
        <container type="folder">2</container>
        <unittitle>1869, 1872 (BPA); 1873 (IAS)</unittitle>
      </did>
    </c02>
  </c01>

  <c01>
    <did>
      <unittitle>Bulletins</unittitle>
      <physdesc>2 folders</physdesc>
    </did>
    <scopecontent>
      <p>Bulletins...</p>
    </scopecontent>
    <c02>
      <did>
        <container type="box">1</container>
        <container type="folder">21</container>
        <unittitle>Bulletins 1945-46</unittitle>
      </did>
    </c02>
    <c02>
      <did>
        <container type="box">2</container>
        <container type="folder">1</container>
        <unittitle>Bulletins 1946-51</unittitle>
      </did>
    </c02>
  </c01>
</root>
```

it produces the desired output:

```
<tr>
   <th>box</th>
   <th>folder</th>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>1839-40, 1846 (SPP); 1852 (BPA); 1854 (SPP)</td>
</tr>    

<tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>1869, 1872 (BPA); 1873 (IAS)</td>
</tr>


<tr>
   <th>box</th>
   <th>folder</th>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>21</td>
   <td>Bulletins 1945-46</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>Bulletins 1946-51</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Note I am assuming that the first c02 child of each c01 element contains all the container types, and each container type only once, as in your sample input. If that is not necessarily true, please clarify the question.